# Input element created under #shadow-root, unable to style it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, input-type-file

I'm attempting to style an `input[type='file']` element using Bootstrap. Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">                          
        <span class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
            Browse 
            <input type='file' id='sample-photo'>
        </span>                         
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled='disabled'>
</div>
```

And is styled with the following CSS:

```
#sample-photo {
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Everything works beautifully, **except** for the `cursor: pointer;` bit in my CSS. When I attempt to inspect the element, **2** input elements appear, 1 in the DOM and one in #shadow-root. When I inspect those 2 elements, it appears like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQalM.jpg

There is another input that is apparently on top of this element, and has its cursor property set to `default`, so my cursor property actually doesn't apply to the element I created, since it sits under this #shadow-root element. How do I fix this problem? What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It works differently in all the browsers because the file input type is quite special.

What browser do you use?

You should create your file input with a normal button with an input text and using jquery.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Try to use this little trick: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/